# How to get data in the form of table in django using cloud firestore?

Tags: django, google-cloud-firestore

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSbiw.png)                                     [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7icpZ.png)                                                         [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chJFr.png)
I'm trying to get data in the form of a table, but the data is not being fetched, I don't know how to get the record, I'm using cloud firestore to get the data.

In my code I have used {{buldings.building}} to get the record but this is not fetching the record from the firebase.

here is my table code for table

```
<div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
          <!-- Simple Tables -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
             <a href="{% url 'building:registerBuilding'%}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle "></i> Add Building</a>
         </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table align-items-center table-flush" id="buildingList">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                  <tr>
                    <th>BUILDING NAME</th>
                    <th>POSTAL CODE</th>
                    <th>CITY</th>
                    <th>STREET</th>
                    <th>HOUSE NO.</th>
                    <th>TOWN</th>
                    <th>ADDITIONAL INFO</th>
                    <th colspan="2">ACTION</th>
                    
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
             {% for building in buildings %}     
           <tr>  
              <td>{{ buildings.building }}</td>  
              <td>{{ buildings.postalCode }}</td>  
              <td>{{ buildings.city }}</td>
              <td>{{ buildings.houseNo }}</td>
              <td>{{ buildings.street }}</td>
              <td>{{ buildings.town }}</td>  
              <td>{{ buildings.additionalInfo }}</td>
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit"  ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>Edit</a></p></td>
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete"  ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a></p></td>  
             </tr>  
            {% endfor %}
               
               
               
              
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!---Container Fluid-->
  </div>
```

views.py file

```
def buildingMag(request):  

context = {
     'buildings': db.collection('Buildings').get()
}
return render(request,"EmployeeAdmin/buildingMag.html",context)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [help] and [ask]. You question is not clear on what exactly your problem is. Please [edit] your question and 1) clarify the problem 2) Add relevant code.

Comment: i have added the changes now

Comment: You aren't passing anything as the context to `render`...

Comment: <td>{{ building.building }}</td>  so this td statement is right? but how this building.building will know that i'm requesting the data to be fetched from the cloud firestore? how things are being linked with .html and views.py file?

Comment: i have updated my code section views.py file, but still no data is fetched

Comment: What does that `print(doc.to_dict())` give you? (Add a sample line to your question) And I thought you wanted to render data from that into the template? Then why are you passing `register_Building.objects.all()` to the context instead of this?

Comment: i have added the print statement just to see the result in my code editor as a test. but this register_Building.objects.all() i have used to to get the record of model, basically i'm also confused that the how the things will work to render the template and to show to the record in buildingMag.html file

Comment: i have updated my views.py file, will it make sense now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.collection('Buildings').get()` should return you a list of Firestore `DocumentSnapshot` which is sent to template context via `buildings` key. Looping through the `buildings` will let you populate the template(table) with each item on the list. Something like below.

In your views construct the dict from `DocumentSnapshot` and return the dict

views.py

```
buildings = db.collection('Buildings').get()
context = {
     'buildings': [building.to_dict() for building in buildings]
}
```

template.html

```
{% for building_obj in buildings %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ building_obj.building }}</td>  
        <td>{{ building_obj.postalCode }}</td>  
        <td>{{ building_obj.city }}</td>
              ...
              ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i have updated my code, data is being fetched but it is not displaying anything, but i have total three entries which are in my firestore database, i only see the edit and delete buttons

Comment: when you say it's not displaying, is it just on the template or Django views itself?
`result = db.collection('Buildings').all()` Can you loop through and print `result` on your views?

Comment: on the template, and db.collection('Buildings').all() instead of this i'm using db.collection('Buildings').get(), when i used .all() this gives an error 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'all' because firestore query for fetch the record is  .get()

Comment: 1. Try adding `{{buildings}}` in the template what does it display. 
2. In your question you have used `<td>{{ building. postalCode }}</td>` two things over there 
                  (1) it's `buildings` plural, as you are passing in the context and 
                  (2) `buildings` is a list you gotta loop through

Comment: i have updated my code, like i have added <td>{{ buildings.postalCode }}</td> . the other thing when i only add {{buildings}} this show objects details :                                                          [<google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x0000027BF472A970>, <google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x0000027BF472A790>, <google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x0000027BF472A8B0>, <google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x0000027BF472A130>]

Comment: Great!!!! the random strings mean that you are receiving the list in the HTML file. Now as you can see `buildings` is a list. You have to loop through each one of them to access its items checkout the for loop snippet in my answer and try it.

Comment: but this is not displaying the record in the form of table, i only see blank entries when i use  <td>{{ buildings.postalCode }}</td> etc.

Comment: Can you post how your template looks after adding the for loop? 

It's no longer `buildings.postalCode` it should be each and every element on the `buildings` list. For example in my case I have used `{% for building_obj in buildings %}` which means `<td>{{ building_obj.postalCode }}</td>`

Comment: 1. Can you post the template html code 
2. JSON screenshot of your firestore

Comment: i have updated the template html code in code section at the top, these two links contains json firestore data screenshot and the other screenshot is when i only add {{buildings}} instead of {{buildings.postalCode}}                                                                                                https://i.stack.imgur.com/7icpZ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSbiw.png

Comment: I have checked the updated code in the question, please not that when looping it's `{{building.postalCode}}` not `buildings` Singular not plural

Comment: i have updated it with building.postalCode  but still this result is displaying                             https://i.stack.imgur.com/chJFr.png

Comment: At this point it's only debugging can you try `{{buildings.0.postalCode}}` somewhere on the HTML

Comment: Found it the query returns Firestore `DocumentSnapshot` and to the data is accessed via data parameter 

https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_document.DocumentSnapshot 

Try  `{{ building.data }}` this should give you a dict

Comment: when i used {{ building.to_dict() }}  this error pops up Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'building.to_dict()'                                                                                                                         and when i used {{building.data}} nothing displays

Comment: Another way is to use `to_dict` on views and then return. Updated the answer can you try that?

Comment: yes, finally it worked!!  thank you so much, I have updated the views.py file with your latest code the thing which I added is this line buildings = db.collection('Buildings').get()   instead of this buildings = db.collection('Buildings').all() and then thing start working :)

Comment: Wonderful, I will update the answer now. would be great if you can upvoie and accept the answer

Comment: yes I have upvoted it, but unfortunately, my profile reputation is below 15 that's why my vote will not be added

Comment: Hi @SaadHassan, you can accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the upvote/downvote arrows.

Comment: @RafaelLemos Done!